# Android: programmatically adding view to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, view, android-activity, popup, android-relativelayout

In my Android application I have an activity featuring GoogleMaps. In case of notifications etc., I show a popup window. This works all quite fine. However, I also have another activity where I want to display the same information in the same way. The idea is to use the same popup window in the corresponding view (View2). The problem is that in this second activity/view the popup window does not appear and the code seems to crash at `group.addView(popup, lp);` (no explicit errors though; but I'm sure there's nothing null). I just don't see the essential difference between the two activities/views that might suggest why the popup windows works fine in the in the one view but not in the other. In the following I show the relevant code snippets.

Here is how I instantiate the popup in both activities. The only difference is the third parameter that refers to the ID of the parent view; a RelativeLayout in each case.

```
// GoogleMaps Activity
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
    [...]
    this.popupPanel = new PopupPanel(this, R.layout.popup, R.id.relativeLayoutMap);
    [...]
}


// View2 Activity
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view2);
    [...]
    this.popupPanel = new PopupPanel(this, R.layout.popup, R.id.relativeLayoutView2);
    [...]
}
```

This is the main code for initializing the popup and for displaying. Only the value ''parentViewID'' differs between the activities.

```
public PopupPanel(Activity activity, int layout, int parentViewID) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.viewID = viewID;

    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) this.activity.findViewById(parentViewID);
    this.popup = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout, parent, false);
}

public void show(boolean alignTop) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) this.activity.findViewById(this.viewID);
    group.addView(popup, lp); // this 'crashes' for the View2 activity
    group.invalidate();
}
```

Finally, here are the snippets of the corresponding layouts. In both cases I refer to a RelativeLayout where I want to place my popup.

```
 <? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout [...]>
     <RelativeLayout [...] android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMap">
         <com.google.android.maps.MapView  [...]/>
     </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

For activity/view View2:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout [...] android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutView2">
     <LinearLayout [...] >
         ...
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout [...] >
         ...
     </LinearLayout>

     <ScrollView [...] >
         <LinearLayout [...] >
            ...
         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Any hints are much appreciated! I know that has been addressed in several question, but my 'problem' is that it basically works. Just only in one activity/view, and not in another. It seems that I miss something rather stupid here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the difference, and as expected that it was something rather stupid: I forgot to put the code that displays the panel not within the `runOnUiThread`. I reallt should have know better by now.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      // code for showing the popup
   }
});
```

One side question: I got on the right track when I put the `addView(...)` call within a try/catch-block. Without it just hangs up there without throwing an error (in LogCat; I'm using Eclipse). Is there a way that such errors are shown by default? Thanks!